# No documents indexed using MongoDB's ElasticSearch river

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I'm trying to use the MongoDB's(2.6.4) river with ElasticSearch(1.3.4). The versions of each are ok.

Creating (PUT : `http://localhost:9200/_river/mongoindex/_meta`)  :

```
{
    "type": "mongodb", 
    "mongodb": { 
      "servers": [
         { "host": "127.0.0.1", "port": 27017 }
      ],
      "db": "fabrice", 
      "collection": "personnes", 
      "gridfs": true
    }, 
    "index": { 
      "name": "mongoindex", 
      "type": "personnes" 
    }
  }
}
```

so :

```
{
    _index: "_river"
    _type: "mongoindex"
    _id: "_meta"
    _version: 1
    created: true
}
```

My bdd is "fabrice", the collection is "personnes". 
So, ok for now.

I add a record in mongo's console:

```
db.personnes.save({nom:'Chief',pays:'UK'})
```

And, at the end, the search query is :

```
http://127.0.0.1:9200/mongoindex/_search?q=pays:UK
```

But no answer :(... :

```
{
    took: 1
    timed_out: false
    _shards: {
        total: 5
        successful: 5
        failed: 0
    }
    hits: {
        total: 0
        max_score: null
        hits: [0]
    }
}
```

Any idea to help me ?

Thanks.
Fabrice

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue.

I have a feeling from looking at ES logs that it's because ES is 1.3.4 instead of 1.3.1 (as per user guide):

https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb

I don't think it supports 1.3.4 :(